# Client's certificate authentication issue in Tomcat in 7.0.100+

Tags: java, tomcat, http-headers, x509certificate

We have client's certificate authentication in our project

However, for some reason after 100 Tomcat release nothing seems to work

We get either `400 HTTP` response or the certificate header is empty (if we set `rejectIllegalHeader="false"`) when we proxy to the application through `nginx`

Example (header's value), name - `ssl_client_cert`:

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\x0A\x09MIIFXDCCA0SgAwIBAgIBBDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBHMQ...
\x0A\x09-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

Or `ssl_client_raw_cert`

```
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\x0AMIIFXDCCA0SgAwIBAgIBBDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBHMQsw ...
y2EmDsw=\x0A-----END CERTIFICATE-----\x0A"
```

I guess here is the commit to blame

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/ae8c82eff96990878e79691819ae941538ee62fd#diff-d4454b2c33deae44a2c2f5cd354aa3ca70c6a268e78c4fd5e1f76fcebc0181ba

Prior to the 100th release everything worked fine

To bypass that we use `ssl_client_escaped_cert` instead.

```
"-----BEGIN%20CERTIFICATE-----%0AMIIFXDCCA0SgAwIBAgIBBDANBgkqhkiG9 ...
qgt0Tzy2EmDsw%3D%0A-----END%20CERTIFICATE-----%0A"
```

Now we have to unescape it manually in Java code

```
 String certificateInfo = URLDecoder.decode(request.getHeader(headerName), "UTF-8");
```

Is there a way we can make Tomcat accept a non-escaped certificate in 100th version and higher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way you can configure Tomcat to allow an HTTP header value than contains 0x0A. Those changes were made in response to [CVE-2020-1935](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-1935).

As an aside, I assume Nginx is performing the client authentication and passing the validated client certificate to Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks a lot, at least now we know that we have to modify our code